# Angularjs pattern "Unexpected next character"

Tags: angularjs, validation, input

Here is the error I receive regarding the following input :
`Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$].`

```
<input
  type='text'
  name="precision"
  ng-model="$ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName]"
  ng-required
  ng-blur="$ctrl.validateInput($ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName], $index)"
  ng-pattern="^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$" />
```

Comment: Try transforming this into a string or a RegExp literal, ie. ng-pattern="'^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$'" (with ' ') or ng-pattern="/^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$/". Can't say for sure but it seems like the issue, could say for sure if we had a working example.

Comment: @Yftach You are right. What doesn't make sense though is that I have another perfectly working example in the same project using the syntax
`ng-pattern="^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$"`

Comment: well at least that used to work but it doesn't anymore since a recent update probably. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ng-pattern instead of just pattern,

```
<input
  name="precision"
  ng-model="$ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName]"
  ng-required
  ng-blur="$ctrl.validateInput($ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName], $index)"
  ng-pattern="^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$" />
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the same error remains.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern had to be written as regular expression

`ng-pattern="/^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$/"`

```
<input
 type='text'
 name="precision"
 ng-model="$ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName]"
 ng-required
 ng-blur="$ctrl.validateInput($ctrl.list[$index][$ctrl.idFieldName], $index)"
 ng-pattern="/^$|^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}$/" />
```